# Simple Cocos2d Iphone Game. Just some basic questions

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I'm making an app, where the sprite has to run across the screen pressing buttons and jumping and ducking. Kind of like line runner. Anyways, I'm using cocos2d. Is this what i should be using. If it is, how would i make it. Im not asking for all the code, just the basic objectives and what i should do! thanks so much!

Comment: google cocos2d game tutorials. no one is going to tell you how to make your game for you. that is way too broad a question.

Comment: I found some but I'm not asking to tell me how to make my game. I'm still learning and would like to know some tips and more.

Answer (score 1):

Cocos2d is one of the best platform to make game i think what you want to do can be done by cocos2d and you need to know how to move object(sprite) across the scene and how to detect the collation.

there is lots of way to move the sprite across the screen you can also move then by the cocos2d built in methods.

search for move method which will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely advise you to use **Cocos2d** for this purpose and also **Box2d** if you need real physics simulation in your game.

Regarding of writing your game have a look [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials) : It contains very useful cocos2d tutorials and even have a tutorial of how to write a full functioning game (Look for the monkey game)

Note : It seems that the link does not work right now but I am sure it will be fixed soon..